# MySQL Query - earn over the average salary

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, average

I am trying to get this query to work. Basically it is getting all people that earn't a degree at Oxford Brookes that now earn a salary over the average salary of the whole database. 
I have searched for hours trying to find a solution. Please feel free to offer advice, so that I may learn from this and solve my issue. Thanks

```
SELECT a.personid,
       a.firstname,
       a.lastname,
       b.placeofstudy,
       AVG(c.salary)
FROM   person a
       INNER JOIN award d
               ON a.personid = d.personid
       INNER JOIN qualification b
               ON d.qualid = b.qualid
       INNER JOIN job c
               ON a.personid = c.personid
WHERE  placeofstudy = 'Oxford Brookes'
GROUP  BY a.personid;
```

This currently produces no errors but does not return the average salary, just each persons current salary.Even when I add 'having c.salary > avg(c.salary)' it refuses to work.

Comment: there is no point is grouping by person id.. each person has unique id

Comment: well, they may have multiple jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.personid, a.firstname, a.lastname, b.placeofstudy, c.salary, (select avg(salary) from job) as AvgSalary
from person a
inner join award d on a.personid = d.personid
inner join qualification b on d.qualid = b.qualid
inner join job c on a.personid = c.personid
where placeofstudy = 'Oxford Brookes'
    and c.salary > (select avg(salary) from job)
```

Comment: Great thanks!! About the only thing I didn't try. One other question though; how do I show the average salary as well as people earning about the average? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the keyword HAVING.

Try this:

```
select a.personid, a.firstname, a.lastname, b.placeofstudy, avg(c.salary) AS avgsalary
from person a
inner join award d
on a.personid=d.personid
inner join qualification b
on d.qualid=b.qualid
inner join job c
on a.personid=c.personid
where placeofstudy = 'Oxford Brookes'
group by a.personid, a.firstname, a.lastname, b.placeofstudy
having c.salary > avgsalary
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'c.salary' in 'having clause' -- Came with this error

Comment: see @RedFilter's answer above. I had misunderstood your question. His solution works for your problem, mine would work in the situation described in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp